# Loop to change one part of a variable name and repeat the command

Tags: r, loops

I am currently using this code to take a variable, select the 2,3,4,5th digits and create a new variable

```
     dataset$nd1_4_digits <- substr(dataset$nd1, 2, 5)
```

I am wanting to repeat this x40 with the part represented by the i increasing by 1 each time so it would be like this;

```
     dataset$ndi_4_digits <- substr(dataset$ndi, 2, 5)
```

In effect the code should do this

```
    dataset$nd1_4_digits <- substr(dataset$nd1, 2, 5) 
    dataset$nd2_4_digits <- substr(dataset$nd2, 2, 5) 
    dataset$nd3_4_digits <- substr(dataset$nd3, 2, 5)
```

and so one up until

```
    dataset$nd40_3_digits <- substr(dataset$nd4, 2, 5)
```

I've looked online at using loops for this but I can't see how to change one part of a variable name unfortunately.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply` :

```
cols <- paste0('nd', 1:40)
dataset[paste0(cols, '_4_digits')] <- lapply(dataset[cols], substr, 2, 5)
```

Or in `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
dataset %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('nd'), list(digits = ~substr(., 2, 5))))
```